# IBM Cloud Private 2.1.0.2 Install Fails - Hostname should be resolved to valid IP address

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I'm trying to install ICP 2.1.0.2 on my Ubuntu 16.04 master node (VM), but the installer fails on "Validating hostname is resolvable" for my 2 worker nodes (2 other VMs) on the same computer.

[image]

I have set up ssh access to all my VMs and I can ping every machine just fine.  My /etc/hosts file is:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
192.168.142.10  icp-master icp-master
192.168.142.11  icp-worker1 icp-worker1
192.168.142.12  icp-worker2 icp-worker2

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

My cluster/hosts file is:

```
[master]
192.168.142.10

[worker]
192.168.142.11
192.168.142.12

[proxy]
192.168.142.10
```

Each of my worker nodes have properly defined hosts files that are consistent with their hostnames.  Adding the -vvv (verbose) option on the install is not providing any additional clarification.

Answer (score 1):

@rhuet The contents of /etc/hosts file you appended should be the one on 192.168.142.10, right? Please also check the /etc/hosts file on 192.168.142.11 and 192.168.142.12. Or you can copy the /etc/hosts file on 192.168.142.10 to other nodes by scp command.

Please ensure the hostname can be resolved to an IP address(e.g.: 192.168.142.x), not the 127.xx.yy.zz, thanks.

Comment: That was the problem.  The /etc/hosts files on my worker nodes did not have entries for themselves.  Now that I've replicated the /etc/hosts file from icp-master to my workers, the install is now working.  Thanks for the help!